# Play() can only be initiated by a user gesture

Tags: android, react-native

I am working on developing an in house API that plays some audio. Essentially, I need to drop some embed code in to my application which provides a play/pause button and plays some audio.

I am using a WebView to embed this code in my application. The player seems to appear in the application although when clicking play, I am getting an error the says `Play() can only be initiated by a user gesture`.

I understand why I am getting this error and why its important to wait for a user gesture. I'd like to adjust my embed code to meet this functionality but am not clear on what I can do to resolve this error and play the audio. Currently, the audio doesn't automatically begin to play, the user must click the play button in the embed code.

Also, whats a bit odd, is that embedding a YouTube video works fine, I am curious as to why YouTube embeds work while my embed doesn't.

Comment: can you please post your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in here is in the code embed, not with react-native. Webview has a [property](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#mediaplaybackrequiresuseraction) called mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction wich is true by default, try setting it to false to see if it helps